# To find the minimum value of $n$ such that $2$ points exist not more than $2cm$ apart on square

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

We take $n$ arbitary points on or inside a square of side $2cm$ such that there will always be a pair of points at a distance of not more than $2cm$. What is the minimum value of $n$?
$(1) 2$
$(2) 4$
$(3) 5$
$(4) 8$

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Maybe Sylvester-Gallai theorem could help but I don't think I can use it. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum number $\mathcal{N}$ is $4$.

It is very easy to show $\mathcal{N} \le 5$. Just divide the square
into four squares of side $1$. If you pick $5$ points from the big square, 
one of the small squares will contain more than one points. The distances among the points in that small square will be no more than $\sqrt{2}$.

$\require{cancel}\cancel{\color{gray}{\text{I don't know any elegant proof for }\mathcal{N} \le 4}}$. Following is my first attempt of a proof of $\mathcal{N} \le 4$. It mimic the approach found in a paper by J.Schaer ${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$.

---

Let $[4] = \{1,2,3,4\}$.

WOLOG, choose a coordinate system so that the square is $S = [-1,1]^2$.
If $\mathcal{N} > 4$, we can choose $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in S$ 
such that $|x_i - x_j| > 2$ whenever $i,j \in [4]$ and $i \ne j$.

For any $u \in [0,2)$, let $U_k, k \in [4]$ be following 4 squares.
$$\begin{array}{ll}
  U_1(u) = [-1,-1+u]^2,& U_2(u) = [1-u,1] \times [-1,-1+u],\\
  U_3(u) = [1-u,1]^2,   & U_4(u) = [-1,-1+u]\times[1-u,1]
\end{array}$$

It is clear $S = \bigcup_{i\in[4]} U_i(\sqrt{2})$. Since the diameter of $U_i(\sqrt{2})$ is $2$, if any $U_i$ contains more than one points,
say $x_j$ and $x_k$, then $|x_j - x_k| \le 2$. Contradict with our choice 
of $x_j$ and $x_k$.

From this, we can deduce $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4  \in \bigcup_{i\in[4]} U_i(2-\sqrt{2})$. Furthermore, each square contains exactly one of the points. Relabeling $x_k$ if necessary, we can assume $x_k \in U_k(2-\sqrt{2})$ for $k \in [4]$.

For any $u \in (0,1)$, let $\mathcal{S}(u)$ be the statement
$$\mathcal{S}(u) \stackrel{def}{=}  x_k \in U_k(u), \forall k \in [4]$$

For any $u$ that $\mathcal{S}(u)$ is true, let $v = 2 - \sqrt{4-u^2}$ and consider following two rectangles
$$[-1,1-v] \times [-1,-1+u] \supset U_1(u)\quad\text{ and }\quad [1-u,1] \times [+1+v,1] \supset U_3(u)$$
Both rectangles have diameter $2$. Since the first rectangle contains $x_1$ while the second rectangle contains $x_3$, none of them contains $x_2$. This implies
$x_2 \in U_2(v)$. Apply similar arguments to other points, we obtain $x_k \in U_k(v)$ for $k = 1,3,4$ too. To summarize, we have shown

$$\mathcal{S}(u)\quad\implies\quad\mathcal{S}(2 - \sqrt{4 - u^2})$$

Construct a sequence $u_n$ by 
$$u_n = \begin{cases}
2-\sqrt{2},& n = 0\\
2 - \sqrt{4-u_{n-1}^2}, & n > 0
\end{cases}$$
Since $\mathcal{S}(u_0)$ is true, $\mathcal{S}(u_n)$ is true for all $n$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = 0$, this leads to

$$x_k \in \bigcap_{n=0}^\infty U_k(u_n) = U_k(0), \forall k \in [4]$$

This means $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are the four vertices of $S$. In particular,
$x_1 = (-1,-1)$ and $x_2 = (1,-1)$ and $|x_1 - x_2| = 2$. This contradicts with our choice of $x_1, x_2$.

Our original assumption $\mathcal{N} > 4$ cannot be true and hence $\mathcal{N} \le 4$.

Since it is trivial to find $3$ points in $S$ at a distance $> 2$ apart, we have
$\mathcal{N} > 3$. As a result, the minimum number $\mathcal{N}$ is $4$.

---

**Update**

I figure out a simpler argument for $\mathcal{N} \le 4$.

Once again, let say we have $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \in S$ with $|x_i - x_j| > 2$ whenever $i \ne j$. Since the circle centered at origin $O$ with radius $2$ completely cover $S$. If any one of $x_k$ is $O$, there will be no more room for other three points.

This means none of $x_k$ is $O$. If $(r_k,\theta_k)$ is the polar coordinates for $x_k$, $\theta_k$ will be well defined (up to multiples of $2\pi$). It is clear we can pick a pair whose "$\theta$" is at most $\frac{\pi}{2}$ apart. Rotating/Reflecting the square and relabeling $x_k$ is necessary, we can assume

$$\theta_1 \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4} ),\; \theta_2 \in [\theta_1,\theta_1 + \frac{\pi}{2}]\quad\implies\quad
x_1, x_2 \in \bigg\{ p \in S : \theta_1 \le \theta(p) \le \theta_1 + \frac{\pi}{2} \bigg\}$$
Notice the set on RHS has diameter $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\cos\theta_1} \le 2$. This forces $|x_1 - x_2| \le 2$ and contradicts with our choices of $x_1, x_2$.

**References**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$  J.Schaer, *The densest packing of 9 circles in a square*,  Can. Math. Bull., 8 (1965), 273-277. An online copy is available on [CMB](https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CMB-1965-018-9).

Comment: +1 for the polar coordinates proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate proof using $1$-norm / Manhattan distance:**

Assume (for later contradiction) that the 4 points are s.t. each pair is $> 2cm$ apart.  Divide the $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ square into 4 separate $1\times 1$ smaller squares and applying the pigeonhole principle, it is clear that the 4 points must reside one per smaller square.  Starting from the point inside $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ name the 4 points clockwise as $p_i = (x_i, y_i)$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4.$

```
+---+---+
| p4| p1|
+---+---+
| p3| p2|
+---+---+
```

Now consider $X = |x_1 - x_2| + |x_2 - x_3| + |x_3 - x_4| + |x_4 - x_1|$.  By considering all possible orderings (of which there are 4, namely: which of $\{x_1, x_2\}$ is more positive $\times$ which of $\{x_3, x_4\}$ is more negative), it is easy to show that $X = 2 (\max(x_1, x_2) - \min(x_3, x_4)) \le 4$.

Similarly, $Y = |y_1 - y_2| + |y_2 - y_3| + |y_3 - y_4| + |y_4 - y_1| = 2 (\max(y_1, y_4) - \min(y_2, y_3)) \le 4$.

The $1$-norm distance, aka Manhattan distance, between two points is defined as $m(p_i, p_j) = |x_i - x_j| + |y_i - y_j|$.  Combining this with $X, Y$ we have:

$X + Y = m(p_1, p_2) + m(p_2, p_3) + m(p_3, p_4) + m(p_4, p_1) \le 8$

This implies we have at least one pair s.t. $m(p_i,p_j) \le 2$.  Finally, triangle inequality ensures that the Euclidean ($2$-norm) distance $\le$ Manhattan distance, completely the contradiction.

Comment: +1 interesting proof, I'll never thought of using Manhattan distance.

Comment: not a generally useful technique at all, but does simplify the proof in this very simple case where some $m(p_i, p_j) \le 2$ is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

The vertices are four points that are 2 cm apart. Any fifth point will be less than 2 cm from at least one of the vertices.